# Matching type of head/tail pattern match argument

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm working on question P07 of [Ninety-Nine Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/):

```
P07 (**) Flatten a nested list structure.
Example:
scala> flatten(List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8))))
res0: List[Any] = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
```

My initial attempt at a solution was:

```
def flatten[A](ls : List[A]): List[A] = {
   def flattenRec[A](ls: List[A], flatList: List[A]): List[A] = ls match {
     case Nil => flatList
     case head: List[A] :: tail =>  flattenRec(head ::: flatten(tail), flatList)
     case head :: tail => flattenRec(tail, flatList :+ head)
   }
   flattenRec(ls, List[A]())
 }
```

however this doesn't compile as I'm not allowed to specify a type for `head` in the second `case` statement. Is there a way for me to do this?

As an aside, the recommended solution uses `flatMap` instead of `match`, but I'm not sure why it even needs pattern matching in that case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just bracket the declaration of head:

```
def flatten[A](ls : List[A]): List[A] = {
  def flattenRec[A](ls: List[A], flatList: List[A]): List[A] = ls match {
    case Nil => flatList
    case (head: List[A]) :: tail => flattenRec(head, flatList)
    case head :: tail => flattenRec(tail, flatList :+ head)
  }
  flattenRec(ls, List[A]())
}
```

Note that you will get a warning about the type pattern being unchecked (because the fact that head needs to be a list of `A` and not anything else will be lost at runtime due to erasure), which you will need to assure yourself you can ignore (or run through some hijinks involving `TypeTag`s).

Answer (score 0):

Nice problem and an alternate solution below:

```
def flatten(a:List[Any]):List[Any] = 
   a.flatMap{
      case l:List[Any] => flatten(l)
      case l => List(l)
   }
```